# Update document metadata in a library via PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, managed-metadata

I'd like to be able to update some files propreties via Powershell, so here the script I tried:

```
[System.Array]$Words = 'Project Overview','Project from pervious Years'
foreach($folder in $list.RootFolder.SubFolders) {
    if ($folder.Name -ne "Reports") {
        foreach($file in $folder.Files) 
            if ($Words –contains $file.Name) {
                $file.CheckOut();
                $file.Properties['Status'] = "9. Old"
                $file.Properties.Update();
                $file.CheckIn('Test'); 
            }
        }
   }
}
```

the files I want to modify are stored in my Reports folder, so once I'm in this folder I loop all files until I find a files whose the name is included in my array, I update the files and then I continue
I don't know why but my code doesn't work and as it's the first I tried to do something via powershell, maybe something is wrong in my code
Thank you

Comment: Are you using Server Side Object Model or Client site object model to connect Sharepoint? Also What I see in your code that you missing `{` on second for loop

Comment: Your IF condition is wrong. It is looking for folder names not equal to Reports.

Answer (score 1):

The following PowerShell script for your reference.

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

#Get the Web
$web=Get-SPWeb "http://sp2013/sites/team"
#Get the List/Library
$list=$web.Lists.TryGetList("Library")

[System.Array]$Words = 'Project Overview','Project from pervious Years'

foreach($folder in $list.RootFolder.SubFolders) {
    if ($folder.Name -eq "Reports") {
        foreach($file in $folder.Files){
            if ($Words –contains $file.Name.split('.')[0]) {                
                $file.CheckOut()
                $file.Properties["Status"] = "9. Old"
                $file.Update()
                $file.CheckIn('Test')
            }
        }
    }
}
```