# Content Organizer rules running on new documents but not old ones

Tags: document-library, content-organizer

I have a drop-off library in SharePoint with 1000+ documents that I want to run newly-created organiser rules against, where the documents should be moved to a new document library based on metadata.

I'm noticing that the rules are being run against newly uploaded documents but not against the ones that existed in the drop-off library before I created the content organiser rule.

Is there a way to run the organiser rule against the older documents?

Answer (score -1):

SharePoint does not provide a built-in feature to apply Content Organizer rules to existing documents in the Drop Off library.

If you need to apply the rules to existing documents, you may need to manually move or re-upload the documents to the Drop Off library so that the rules can be applied.

See: [Apply Content Organizer Rules when Sharepoint receives a new document via email](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/284233/apply-content-organizer-rules-when-sharepoint-receives-a-new-document-via-email)

And: [Update document metadata in a library via PowerShell](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/266638/update-document-metadata-in-a-library-via-powershell)

You can try with PowerShell (edit: UPDATE)

```
# Load SharePoint Snapin
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

# Set the URL of your site
$siteURL = "http://YourSiteURL"

# Get the SPWeb object for the site
$web = Get-SPWeb $siteURL

# Get the Drop Off library
$dropOffLib = $web.Lists["Drop Off Library"]

# Loop through each item in the Drop Off library
foreach ($item in $dropOffLib.Items)
{
    # Check out and check in each item to trigger an update
    $item.File.CheckOut()
    $item.File.CheckIn("Updated to apply rules")
}
```

Comment: I am trying to avoid doing this because it is 1000+ documents. Any what we can trigger this via PowerShell?

Comment: Yes you can with PowerShell, ill update my response with the code snippet, please test and let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Hi Martin. Your Answer is related to creating a new Content Organiser rule. That's not my issue. That does not help with running the Organiser rule against existing document.

Comment: To be fair, the Powershell snippet you posted is how to **create** a _new_ content organizer rule, not **trigger** an existing rule on existing documents.  To do that you would have to use Powershell to trigger an `update` on each of the documents in the drop-off library.

Comment: @DylanCristy Thank you for pointing that out. I have updated the code and added another reference, please test.

Comment: @user1913559 I have updated my comment, please see before downvoting.